# How to convert GOES-R (15) IR image from gray-scale to brightness temprature

Tags: qgis, remote-sensing, satellite, digital-image-processing

How do I convert satellite IR images taken by GOES-R (15) from gray-scale to brightness temperature? We can download the IR satellite images, and read its RGBA values. But how can we convert this RGBA value into cloud temperature?

Comment: There are over 2000 satellites in orbit around the Earth. It matters when you're asking questions to specify which satellite and sensor you're referring to.

Comment: I am interested in the GOES-R (15) IR images.

Answer (score 1):

Which satellite? Landsat 8 for example: see the bottom bit here http://landsat.usgs.gov/Landsat8_Using_Product.php

Comment: This could be considered a link only answer, which is generally discouraged on GIS.SE. Links can go dead in the future, rendering the answer useless. You should at least summarize or describe the information contained at the link here to ensure it can remain useful in such an event.